# STDEVIFS: Just like AVERAGEIFS, How?

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, stdev

The code below gives me the average value of a data comlumn (`ZENIT!H:H`), using a specific range (`K2 & K3`) of another data column (`ZENIT!N:N`).

```
=AVERAGEIFS(ZENIT!H:H,ZENIT!N:N,"<="&K2,ZENIT!N:N,">"&K3)
```

Now i want to get the standard deviations instead of the averages, what formula can I use.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried stdev()? Does stdevifs() exist?

Comment: I have tried =STDEV.S(IF((K2>ZENIT!N:N>K3),ZENIT!H:H)) and some variations of that. But when a different range is specified it returns the exactly the same value, when it should at least be a bit different. Since the different range includes different ZENIT!H:H values. That leads me to believe that it does not function as i want it to. And the stdevifs() is not a thing, at least not in Excel 2010.